# How to use TableView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am relatively new to the world of Xamarin.Forms and have a question with regard to Xamarin TableView.

I want to create a layout similar to the one shown below.

[image: Desired Layout with Xamarin TableView]

Question is, can I use [TableView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview) for this or is there an another option for this? Can anyone show this with XAML code please?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Tabs in the bottom are not required.

Answer (score 3):

I don't mean to be rude, but this is very easy to retrieve from the [documentation pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview) and a bit of trying yourself.

To get you started, try this:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
    <TableView.Root>
        <TableView.Section>
            <ImageCell Text="Invoice Customization" Source="Invoice_image.png" />
            <ImageCell Text="Invoice Defaults" Source="Invoice_image.png" />
        </TableView.Section>
        <TableView.Section Title="Security">
            <SwitchCell Text="Use Touch ID" />
        </TableView.Section>
        ... etc.
   </TableView.Root>
</TableView>
```

The arrows at the end of the cells and the footer text underneath the Security section are not possible with Xamarin.Forms out of the box, this will probably require you to write a custom renderer.

Comment: I agree. I am not able to figure out the ability to navigate when i click a cell.

Comment: My confusion is, will it add right arrow on the ios automatically or I need to do something about it?

Comment: It will not add it automatically, they are called accessories (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/) as mentioned, if you need these, you will need to create a custom renderer

Comment: Can you share an example? I am developing an apps for Android and iOS so it must work on both

Comment: It's not going to work on both since this is iOS specific. If you want it on both you will have to design a arrow icon yourself and draw is at the end of your cell.